# onResult call when user has made his selections

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, start-activity

I  have a listview with some cetegories which are checkable. I want to start this activity with `startActivityForResult` and when the users returns to the initial activity this activity will start founding the categories which have been selected and store their ids in a list. The problem is where should i call the `onResult` method. My first thought is to put it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(isFinishing()){
      onResult()....call here       
    }
}
```

However, as I know the `isFinishing()` is not the best way to be sure that the activity is finishing and that we can't be sure when it will be called. Is there any better way to return results when the user have finished checking his categories? I mean that I can't send `onResult` every time the user makes a selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to call `onResult()` when you want to identify your activity's result, instead use `setResult` whenever the user makes a selection and when your activity finishes the last set result will propagate back to the activity that started your activity for result.

The code should look like:

```
onItemSelected(){ // or onClick
     getItem();
     setResult();
}
```

Comment: would it be better if i put the setResult in finish method from Activity?

Comment: you can do that if you do keep track of your selection, but keep in mind that android doesn't ensure call back of all of life-cycle methods ... so in some cases your onPause may not get excuted

Comment: do you mean onFinish there where you say onPause?

Comment: there is no onFinish method, I was talking about finishing callbacks (onPause , onStop, onDestroy )

Answer (score 0):

Call the `setResult(int resultCode, intent data)` during the selection and override the onActivityResult in your previous activity.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

  //do something here.

}
```

I hope this helps you... :)